# VTK Image slices to volume (C++)

Tags: vtk, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to display a volume slices-composed in QT5+VTK 7.0.0. However, I don't know why using **vtkImageSlice**+**vtkImageStack** only shows me **one** slice instead of **five** slices. This is the code I'm using it:

```cpp
/*This function receives an ultrasound image from network.
The function is working fine if we display the 2D images,
but I want to stack a bunch of images in a volume.
The imageStack at the end always keeps one image only.*/
void WDisplay::Disp(QImage b)
{
    // qimagevtk is a vtkSmartPointer<vtkQImageToImageSource> type
    qimagevtk->SetQImage(&b);
    qimagevtk->Update();
    // imageSliceMapper is a vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageSliceMapper> type
    imageSliceMapper->SetInputData(qimagevtk->GetOutput());
    // imageSliceMapper is a vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageSlice> type
    imageSlice->SetMapper(imageSliceMapper);
    imageSlice->GetProperty()->SetOpacity(.5);

    // Stack
    // vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageStack>
    imageStack->AddImage(imageSlice);
    if(!(idx<5)) //idx initialized at zero in the constructor
    {
        // m_renderer ---> vtkRenderer
        m_renderer->AddViewProp(imageStack);
        m_renderer->Render();
        // wvtk ---> QVTKWidget
        wvtk->GetInteractor()->Render();
        idx = 0;
    }
    else
        idx++;
}
```

This is the output (screenshot) I got when I run the function:
[image: screenshot]

> Every vtk object was created in the constructor using **vtkSmartPointer<*vtk object type*>::New()**. I hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slices in vtkImageStack are in the same physical location, think layers in photoshop. Therefore you need to assign the layer number for each image slice.

Have a look at [vtkImageProperty::SetLayerNumber(int)](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageProperty.html#ac2c1b6c138e1112469beb10783c4dcaa) and [vtkImageStack::SetActiveLayer(int)](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageStack.html#a52e5802a1349528dfbc0d7e735835ef1).

Create a different lookup table to map for each slice, or change the opacity, so that you can see through the slices in the stack.

And do everyone who reads your code a favor and change `if(!(idx<5))` to `if(idx>=5)`.

HTH,

Miro

Comment: Thank you! As I want a volume I better changed the vtkImageStack for vtkImageAppend.